# Paypal purchase promise

Tags: paypal, promise

there is a way to make a kind of promise of payment through paypal? I'll explain. I have to sell some objects, but will go into production only if I sell 1,000 pieces. everything will be explained on the website and it will all be on the rule. I would like to make a system that by filling out a form at the end give the option to pay with PayPal, but that actually do the transaction only when I will want (when I get to 1000 pieces) if I do not sell all the pieces no one will have to pay the money. thank you all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming but is instead a product specific question related to what can be accomplished with PayPal payment solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about PayPal, I don't think they allow such action. Depending on your situation, if possible, I recommend Stripe. Stripe has this function and you can save the encrypted customer details (securely on their server) and execute the actual payment at a later date. Stripe is not available worldwide so you will have to check with them if they operate in your area. Otherwise, I do not think this will be possible without some very bad practices like self storing card details (Do not do it). I hope this helps.